How to tell the difference between neutral and ground bar in panel
I’m trying to install a 50 amp generator inlet.


Not the question but 1. The inlet needs to be in positions 2,4 and your branch wires have all been annoyingly trimmed to length so the wires that are there now will have to be extended to reach the open positions below.  2. Idk if you can get two pole 50a plug on neutral breaker and idk if I see space for #8 wire on your buses.   You may need a special lug for the inlet's neutral.  Read the panel instructions.

If the ground wire is copper, 50A only needs 10 AWG ground.

Neutral is isolated from the panel (or can be, if a main panel where it's bonded to ground.) That means there's an insulator between the bar and the metal case of the panel. Ground bars that are actually separate are directly connected to the panel with no insulator.
In the case of a main panel (or a decades-old sub-panel in a grandfathered condition) the grounds can share space on the bonded-to-ground (usually but not always with a green screw) neutral bar or bars.
Many panels have a neutral bar on each side; both are neutral bars.
Now that you've added a picture, we can see that you have a bonded (green screw in upper right position) plug-on-neutral panel. Both bars are Neutrals, but because they are bonded in a main panel, grounds can share space on them. The two bars are joined to each other and the neutral lug out of sight in the plastic insulator.
There are holes pre-drilled in the case if you wanted to add dedicated ground bars, but you don't appear to need them. You might want to pick up a pair of "service entrance barriers" to cover the incoming line lugs, however. Makes working in the panel safer by insulating the parts you can't shut off.
